# Using Bootstrap 4 To Change Color and Position in One Class

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am Using Bootstrap 4, and I want the text to be moved to the middle and the text color to be white in one class. For Example:

```
<p class="text-center white">Center aligned text.</p>
```

This doesn't seem to work. My website is https://beggweb.000webhostapp.com, and the text is still too dark to see underneath the Carousel, which I want the text to be white. How can It be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class name is text-white in Bootstrap 4:

```css
p {
  background-color: coral;
}

div {
  background-color: teal;
}

.textWhite {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<p class="text-center text-white">Center aligned text.</p>

<div class="textWhite">If you're using Bootstrap 3, you can create your own text white class</div>
```

Comment: I didn't work. My CND is <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>. When I add the other CND, it messes up the rest of the code

Comment: Oh, I see. That would be Bootstrap 3. I don't think 3 uses text-white and only has text-muted, text-primary, text-success, text-info, text-warning, and text-danger. You can create your own class though.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Thank you. I thought I was using 4

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

CSS

```
.text-center  {background-color: coral; position: absolute; left: 150px; top: 150px;}
```

HTML

```
<p class="text-center text-white">Center aligned text.</p>
```

If you need to change front color, you can use color:yourcolor;